# Parsing Alamofire result into objects in Swift (using: Alamofire, SwiftyJSON & ObjectMapper)

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm having problems parsing the incoming JSON.

This is my function:

```
func postCheckUserPhonenumbers(phonenumbers:[String], completionHandler: (([AnyObject?], AnyObject?) -> Void)) {
        let urlString = Constant.apiUrl().stringByAppendingFormat(Constant.apiPostCheckUserPhonenumbers)

        let phoneNumbersDictionary = phonenumbers.map({ ["number": $0] })

        let JSON = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(phoneNumbersDictionary, options: [])

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = JSON

        Alamofire.request(request).validate().responseJSON(completionHandler: {response in
            if response.result.isSuccess{
                if let value = response.result.value {
//                    let json = JSON(value)
                    if let users:Array<User> = Mapper<User>().mapArray(value) {
                        completionHandler(users, nil)
                    } else {
                        completionHandler([nil], nil)
                    }
                }
            }
            if response.result.isFailure{
                let message = ApiMessage()
                message.message = "No users found"
                completionHandler([nil],message)
            }
        })
    }
```

[image]

Normally I cast the result into a JSON first but this time I get compile errors when trying to do that:

[image]

Comment: you've got a variable called JSON which is a NSData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed my JSON variable declared above the function. I've now got this:

```
func postCheckUserPhonenumbers(phonenumbers:[String], completionHandler: (([AnyObject?], AnyObject?) -> Void)) {
    let urlString = Constant.apiUrl().stringByAppendingFormat(Constant.apiPostCheckUserPhonenumbers)

    let phoneNumbersDictionary = phonenumbers.map({ ["number": $0] })

    let inputJSON = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(phoneNumbersDictionary, options: [])

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = inputJSON

    Alamofire.request(request).validate().responseJSON(completionHandler: {response in
        if response.result.isSuccess{
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                let jsonString = json.rawString()
                if let users:Array<User> = Mapper<User>().mapArray(jsonString) {
                    completionHandler(users, nil)
                } else {
                    completionHandler([nil], nil)
                }
            }
        }
        if response.result.isFailure{
            let message = ApiMessage()
            message.message = "No users found"
            completionHandler([nil],message)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You are not using SwiftyJSON here. In this example, you are parsing JSON into JSON object and later using only string representation so ObjectMapper will parse it again (from the string this time). Consider using package https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper . Or do similar by hands.